# How I can send email from my app without using intents, in background, and without enabling "less secure apps" in google security

Tags: java, android

I know how to send mail using intents and SMTP and Java mail, but how I can send email from my app without using intents, in background, and without enabling "less secure apps" in google security

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. Please got through the link on how to ask effective questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What's wrong with using JavaMail? I've used it without problem

Comment: For javaMail we need to enable "Less secure apps", I don't want to do like that. If i click a button mail has to send